# How do I view JSON data from an arbitrary link within my app?

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-strap

I can view content from specific json array data from an arbitrary link within the app?

As my demo plunker shows, my search works fine (search the term "content") and returns what I'd like; but I also want to be able to recall some of that returned data from certain links elsewhere in the app.

Plunker scenario: 
Clicking "View the info for content set 3" link in my plunker should show the info in content set 3 below it, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Plunker Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8A8nJ6uQfdTwR2TGRtY?p=preview

I'm also curious how I could keep the content visible when I refresh the page?

HTML

```
<!-- Search -->
<div class="well"> 
  <p>Search the term "content"</p>
  <form role="form">
    <div my-search ng-model="selectedContent" class="form-group clearfix search">
      <input type="text" ng-model="selectedContent" ng-options="query as query.searchQuery for query in searchData" bs-typeahead="bs-typeahead" class="form-control search-field"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-btn" ng-click="updateModel()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- this link should also return the specified data -->
<a href="">View info for content set 3:</a>

<!-- Dynamic Content -->
<div class="well">
  <h4>{{clickedContent.contentTitle}}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in clickedContent.headlines" ng-bind-html="toTrusted(item.headline)"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

AngularStrap Typeahead partial template

```
   <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1" ng-show="$isVisible()" role="select">
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="match in $matches" ng-class="{active: $index == $activeIndex}">
          <a href="" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="updateModel(); $select($index, $event)">
              <div class="query" ng-bind="match.label" data-title="{{match.value.popoverTitle}}", data-content="{{match.value.popoverContent}}", data-placement="right", data-trigger="hover", bs-popover></div>
          </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
    var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
    .config(function ($typeaheadProvider) {
      angular.extend($typeaheadProvider.defaults, {
        template: 'ngstrapTypeahead.html',
        container: 'body'
      }); 
    });

    app.directive('mySearch', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel){
          ngModel.$render = function(){
             if (angular.isObject($scope.selectedContent)) {
               $scope.clickedContent = $scope.selectedContent;
             }
          }
           $scope.updateModel = function() {
             $scope.clickedContent = $scope.selectedContent;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    function MainController($scope, $sce, $templateCache, $http) {

      $scope.selectedContent = '';

      $http.get('searchData.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.searchData = response.data;
        return $scope.searchData;
      });

      $scope.toTrusted = function(headlineHtml) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(headlineHtml)
      };

    };
```

JSON

```
     [
        {
            "contentId": 1,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 1 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 1",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>1st headline in content set 1</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>2nd headline in content set 1</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>3rd headline in content set 1</a>"
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "contentId": 2,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 2 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 2",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>1st headline in content set 2</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>2nd headline in content set 2<a/>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>3rd headline in content set 2</a>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "contentId": 3,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 3 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 3",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>1st headline in content set 3</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>2nd headline in content set 3</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>3rd headline in content set 3</a>"
                }
            ]
        },
            {
            "contentId": 4,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 4 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 4",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>1st headline in content set 4</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>2nd headline in content set 4</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#'>3rd headline in content set 4</a>"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Move getting searchData.json from your controller and into a service. This service can cache the data, so that every the data is needed it does not need to request it again. Then this service can be injected into any controller or directive that needs the data.

Comment: Thanks Martin, the service automatically cache's the data which will allow me to refresh and keep the data visible?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand how to cache dynamic templates (based on json data) on app load so that the urls work beforehand.